# I have a problem on sending Downstream to a gateway

Tags: shell

I'm using a dragino DLOS8 gateway and a dragino end node lt-22222-l. I wrote a script to read and show the values in my end node's inputs but I couldn't control my relays. I found an example of a script (in a dragino article titled Communication with ABP End Node) showing this function to control them( it controlled the digital outputs but I changed it to relays) which is:

```
echo "${DEV_2},imme,hex,030101" > /var/iot/push/down
```

I even tried with more specified one:

```
echo "${DEV_1},imme,hex,030101,20,1,SF12,869525000,1" > /var/iot/push/down
```

in the article it indicates that I have to create a file in the directory /var/iot/push for downstream purpose. I tried using winscp and the command touch down but it deleted few seconds after. if there is anyone that used those devices or knows about this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Dragino, also with device logfiles in /var/iot/channels directory. Got information from Dragino support that those files are "consumed" by MQTT and TCP processes, so are periodically deleted: I undestand that LoRaWAN or MQTT or TCP application has to work with those files as soon as they are generated.
Notice that "imme" sends downstream immediately to C type devices, maybe "time" (downstream after receiving data from node) is better for your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "${DEV_1},imme,hex,030101" > /var/iot/push/test
```

Are you able to find some other script made by Dragino?